# Storing Geolocation Data to a file on a server using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, geolocation

I am trying to store the geolocation coordinates to an array which I save to a file using php, but it is giving me errors, is there another way to do this through javascript or ajax?

```
<?php

$array = array();
$navigator->geolocation->getCurrentPosition(function ($position) use (&$array) {
$lat = $position->coords->latitude;
$lon = $position->coords->longitude;
array_push($array, $lat);
});

$filename = "geo.php";
$mystring = implode("\n", $array);
$numbytes = file_put_contents($filename, $mystring . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

print "$numbytes bytes written\n";


?>
```

Comment: It is giving you **what error**... go on give us a clue!

Comment: Where do you instantiate `$navigator` is that the error

Comment: the error is is giving me is " Fatal error: Call to a member function getCurrentPosition() on null  on line 4 " @RiggsFolly